# Not able to pass an object in writeFile method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I want to write into json file .I want to write an object that i am passing
Here is the code

```
path.exists(logfile_name, function(exists) {
    if (!exists) {
         var jsonObject={ "req": req,
                     "result": result ,
                      "fields": fields } ;

            fs.writeFile(logfile_name ,jsonObject,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("error is: " + err)
            }
            else
                console.log("no error found");

             });
    }

});
```

In logfile_name it writes
      [object Object]
But i want it to write like this
{
"req": value,
"result": value ,
"fields": value}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't pass a string or a buffer to `writeFile`, the `toString` function of what you pass is called. In your case it returns `"[object Object]"`.

You have to convert it yourself :

```
fs.writeFile(logfile_name, JSON.stringify(jsonObject), function(err){
```

I would advise against naming a JavaScript object variable "jsonObject" : it might create confusion between what is an object and what is some JSON (i.e. a string holding the serialization of an object).

Comment: it is giving an error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON @dystroy

Comment: Well, what's your object ? You can't convert circular objects to JSON. Apart using some library pruning the object from the circular references but that's would be a non reversible conversion.

Comment: what i did is fs.writeFile(logfile_name,JSON.stringify({method:"logic" ,Date:Date()}, null, 4), function(err){